# BX Slider not showing all slides

Tags: jquery, bxslider

Upgraded to latest version of BX slider and I cannot get multiple slides to show.

Like Example #1 
http://bxslider.com/examples/carousel-demystified

The site I'm working on only displays one and I cannot for the life of me figure it out.

http://www.etinteractive.com

```
$('.slider5').bxSlider({
  minSlides: 2,
  maxSlides: 2,
  slideWidth: 360,
  slideMargin: 10
});
```

Comment: I see 3 slides. What seems to be the problem? is your issue resolved?

Comment: Yea, i kept working at it, Finally figured it all out. It was a combination of the JS file and CSS files. I downloaded a fresh copy and started over and its working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your missing the jquery.bxslider.css file, or forgot to include your CSS in your stylesheet.